# Tool to log function calls?

Tags: c++, debugging, utility

Is there a tool for C++ that can log function calls and what was passed?

Ex:

```
Display::Resize(1024,768)
Player::Jump()
...
```

Or anything somewhat like this to linearly see the flow of execution without having a Log call in every method of every class?

I use Visual  Studio as an IDE, but any external tool or plugin that could do this would be great. Are there any?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more exotic solution could be to have a look a [Aspect-Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). One fundamental example is to log function call.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#cite_note-14) for C++ examples.

Edit : a small example from AspectC++ to trace a call from a member function (Iter::Reset in that case)

```
aspect Tracer
{ 
   advice call("% %Iter::Reset(...)") : before()
   {
      cerr << "about to call Iter::Reset for " << JoinPoint::signature() << endl;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

this might be helpful: [_penter hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and here is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47532/A-Simple-Profiler-using-the-Visual-Studio-C-C-Comp):

Answer (score 0):

You could set up breakpoints that automatically print a backtrace when the functions you're interested in are called with your debugger, or use a specialized tool like [xtrace](http://xtrace.sourceforge.net/).